# pause the player

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

i want to pause the player. but over code only perform start and stop. how we pause the player.

Comment: You've asked 20 questions in 2 months yet you've given no votes nor accepted any answers. It doesn't make people want to help.

Answer (score 0):

i think player.stop() will pause the player. according to blackberry docs.

> public void stop()
>
> ```
>       throws MediaException Stops the Player. It will pause the playback
> ```
>
> at the current media time.

Comment: player.stop(). stop the player not pause the player. if we press the start after the stop the song will start at the starting point not that point where i press the stop. but pause is use to start that point where we press the pause during the song.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code in your start button. It probably calls setMediaTime(0) or something else is. Vivart is correct in that stop() is pause-- it just stops, it has nothing to say about the MediaTime inside the player.